# How to make a "virgin" Google search?

Tags: puzzle-creation

*Disclaimer: this question is intended to be asking for help about puzzle creation, but in a way it can be regarded as a puzzle in itself - except I don't claim to have a very good answer.*

When you create a puzzle, it may be helpful to know what others will see when they run a Google search. The results usually depend on what Google knows about you, your past searches, and so on. What is the most convenient way to ask Google to pretend that it knows nothing about me, so that I have the closest possible idea of what other people are going to see, on average, upon running that search?

Comment: Don't base your puzzle off of that. Search results can and will change over time.

Comment: @FireCubez I know, and I also know that searches made by other people will depend on *their* cookies, but still. Not the heart of a puzzle, juste a side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- I'd start by opening a private window in your browser. All major browsers offer this option nowadays.
- That might not be enough, since location can also have a great influence on your search (depending on context; the influence is greater when you search for 'restaurant' than for 'restaurant in Paris'). You might want to use a VPN to 'hide' your location from the search engine, switch to multiple other countries and check how users in those countries would see the page.
- Try a different search engine. [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) is one that doesn't track you. Still, it doesn't produce the results when your audience is mainly using Google.
- Note that search results may change over time *anyway* (again, some searches might be affected more than others). This might be another challenge for your puzzle.

Comment: I'm not sure using a VPN would help, since Google will then think you're in a different location.

Comment: @msh210 true; at least it offers you the flexibility of *choosing* your location. It can still be helpful to check the differences between e.g. New York and London.

Comment: I'm tempted to accept this answer as you've got very nice ideas - especially the idea of using a private window is effortless and already quite efficient. Unless someone comes later with an absolute killer, the tick is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative option is installing Google on a fresh device you have never used to search with and see the results this returns (e.g. installing the Google app on your phone without syncing your previous history).